# FileUpload asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, file-upload

I want to force my user to only search in a particular folder when using the fileupload control. Is that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's totally up to the client, as long as it's pure HTML, and not, say, ActiveX implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. The standard web browser file upload control can't be restricted in this way.

Comment: Do you want to hint a path to the user?

Answer (score 1):

How do you know that folder exists?

If it's a network share perhaps a better idea would be to have the webserver itself create a listing of all the files and folders at that location and let the user navigate to the appropriate file?

Comment: i like that idea. I'm gonna try and create a modal popup that has a list of thumbnails to select from that file.